# Running ansible but keep getting failed to connect via ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

```
MacBook-Pro:rails1 woo$ ssh vagrant@10.0.1.92
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-91-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Tue Jul  5 03:52:20 UTC 2016

  System load:  0.0               Users logged in:     1
  Usage of /:   4.0% of 39.34GB   IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.15
  Memory usage: 32%               IP address for eth1: 10.0.1.100
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for eth2: 10.0.1.92
  Processes:    80

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud


Last login: Tue Jul  5 03:52:20 2016 from 10.0.1.19
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

But,

```
>ansible -vvvv all -m ping -u vagrant
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
  _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)
Using /Users/woo/vagrant_vms/rails1/ansible.cfg as config file
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
<10.0.1.92> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<10.0.1.92> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ForwardAgent=yes -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.0.1.92 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467746604.02-144506913281055 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1467746604.02-144506913281055="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467746604.02-144506913281055 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
10.0.1.92 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I've done:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh vagrant@10.0.1.92 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

and it was successful as tested by the ssh command.

I don't understand why I keep getting the Failed to connect message.

The 10.0.1.92 is in the hosts file and the ip of the vm is set to that ip.

Comment: are you issuing the ansible command from the same machine where you ssh from (i.e. MacBook-Pro:rails1?)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
ansible -vvvv all -m ping -u vagrant
```

Comment: Same result:
10.0.1.92 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", 
    "unreachable": true
}

Comment: paste the full track please

Comment: Pasted full stack trace above.  Not enough room to do it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to issue these two commands before connecting the vagrant box with Ansible.

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ ssh-add
```